# move data from 1 table to another table in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-8

[image: database table structure]
As indicated I have 2 tables that have similar content... the only difference is the 'watchlist has an extra 'reason field

what I'm trying to achieve is moving the selected data from 1 table to another table and adding ...

so the process is like [image: refer this]

I need to select the row of data and click the button 'add to watchlist ' and input the 'reason' then submit the form. but after I have to click the submit button the following error occurs..  may I ask what part I miss? sorry, I'm just new in Laravel .. Really appreciate any help.
[image: error]

here is my controller

```
  public function AddToWatchlist(Request $request, $id)
    {
       

        $watchlist = new watchlist();

        //Select the data from visitor 
        $record = DB::table('visitors')
        
             ->select('firstname')
             ->select('lastname')
             ->select('email')
             ->select('phonenumber')
            ->where('id',$id)
            ->first();

        //Insert data from visitor to watchlist
        DB::table('watchlist')->insert([

            'firstname' => $record->firstname,
            'lastname' => $record->lastname,
            'email' => $record->email,
            'phonenumber' => $record->phonenumber,
            'reason' => $request->reason


        ]);
       
        //Delete the data from visitor after shifted
        $record->delete();

     
        $watchlist->save();
        return redirect('visitor.visitorlist')>with('status','Student Image Added Successfully' );


    }
```

my viewpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        @if(session('status'))
        <h6 class="alert alert-success">{{ session('status') }}</h6>
        @endif
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4> Visitor List</h4>
                    <a href="{{ url('addvisitor') }}" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Add Visitor</a>
                  
                       
                        <a href="{{ url('addwatchlist') }}" class="btn btn-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                        Add to watchlist
                        
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">



                <table class="table table-borderd table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone number</th>
                             
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($visitor as $item)
                            <tr>
                                <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"></td>
                                <td>{{ $item->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->firstname}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->lastname}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->email}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->phonenumber}}</td>
        
                                 
                                <!-- <td>
                                   <form action="{{ url('delete-student/'.$item->id) }}" method="POST">
                                                    @csrf
                                                    @method('DELETE')
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`
                                   </form>
                                </td> -->
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                </table>


                <!-- Modal -->
                <form action="{{ url('addtowatch/'.$visitor->id) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <label for="reason"> Indicate the reason for adding to watchlist</label>
                            <input type="text" name="reason " class="form-control" name="reason">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
           
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my web.php code

```
Route::post('addtowatch/{id}', [WatchlistController::class, 'AddToWatchlist']);
```

---

update new problem
now the problem are being solve but there is no error ,on getting the property item of 'firstname'.. any idea ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok i got your point.

1. Please use the laravel comment {{-- body --}} instead of the  because it is the blade template engine, not your html file.
2. Your mistake is that you call the modal outside your foreach loop,
   so that the visitor id not found because it is the array not model.
   so...
3. Replace your blade file code with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>

   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">

               @if (session('status'))
                   <h6 class="alert alert-success">{{ session('status') }}</h6>
               @endif
               <div class="card">
                   <div class="card-header">
                       <h4> Visitor List</h4>
                       <a href="{{ url('addvisitor') }}" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Add Visitor</a>


                       <a href="{{ url('addwatchlist') }}" class="btn btn-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                           data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                           Add to watchlist

                       </a>
                   </div>

                   <div class="card-body">



                       <table class="table table-borderd table-striped">
                           <thead>
                               <tr>
                                   <th>#</th>
                                   <th>ID</th>
                                   <th>Firstname</th>
                                   <th>Lastname</th>
                                   <th>Email</th>
                                   <th>Phone number</th>

                               </tr>
                           </thead>

                           <tbody>
                               @foreach ($visitor as $item)
                                   <tr>
                                       <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""
                                               id="flexCheckDefault"></td>
                                       <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ $item->firstname }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ $item->lastname }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ $item->phonenumber }}</td>


                                       {{-- <td>
                                  <form action="{{ url('delete-student/'.$item->id) }}" method="POST">
                                                   @csrf
                                                   @method('DELETE')
                                                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>`
                                  </form>
                               </td> --}}
                                   </tr>

                                   <!-- Modal -->
                                   <form action="{{ url('addtowatch/' . $item->id) }}" method="POST">
                                       @csrf
                                       <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1"
                                           aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                           <div class="modal-dialog">
                                               <div class="modal-content">
                                                   <div class="modal-header">
                                                       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title
                                                       </h5>
                                                       <button type="button" class="btn-close"
                                                           data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="modal-body">
                                                       <label for="reason"> Indicate the reason for adding to
                                                           watchlist</label>
                                                       <input type="text" name="reason " class="form-control"
                                                           name="reason">
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="modal-footer">
                                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                           data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save
                                                           changes</button>
                                                   </div>
                                               </div>
                                           </div>
                                   </form>
                               @endforeach
                           </tbody>
                       </table>

                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>


   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the response , i have tried your suggestion and its work , but there are another problme comes out .. can you check with it? i have update the questions